# PHP - Doctrine - How to autoload entities classes using a single namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, psr-0

I have a group of PHP files containing classes (entities). Each class has the same namespace:

```
// src/App/Entity/Actions.php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Actions
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Actions
{
// SOME CODE
```

I autoload the PHP files containing the classes with composer:

> ```
> "autoload": {
>     "psr-0": {
>         "App": "src/"
>     }
> }
> ```

And in my bootstrap.php file, I add this line:

```
 use App\Entity;
```

So I figured that because told the app to use the App\Entity namespace, that I can just call the entity classes like this: `$entity = new Actions();`

but when I try that, I get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Actions' not found in    C:\wamp64\www\spider\chebi2\inc\orm_tools.php on line 49

If I do this:

```
use App\Entity; use App\Repository;

if (class_exists('Actions')) { dump('exists'); } else { dump('not exists'); }

if (class_exists('\App\Entity\Actions')) { dump('exists'); } else { dump('not exists'); }
```

Heres what it outputs:

```
PS C:\wamp64\www\spider\chebi2> php .\get_actions.php
"not exists"
"exists"
```

So it can only find the class when I provide the full namespace. And weirdly enough, when I tried this:

```
// Direct path to the Actions.php file
use App\Entity\Actions;

if (class_exists('Actions')) { dump('exists'); }
else { dump('not exists'); }

if (class_exists('\App\Entity\Actions')) { dump('exists'); }
else { dump('not exists'); }
```

I get the same result:

```
PS C:\wamp64\www\spider\chebi2> php .\get_actions.php
"not exists"
"exists"
```

So now I'm even more confused. What is the point in using: `use App\Entity;` if it doesn't actually make the classes in that namespace directly available? And why is assigning the direct path to the class `use App\Entity\Actions;` not even working?

Am I doing something wrong here? Is there a correct way to use namespaces that I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 1):

PSR-0 is depracated you should use PSR-4

in PSR-4

**composer.json**

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
         "App\\": "src/",
    }
 }
```

in directory src/ which is on same level as composer.json add directory `Entity` so in path `src/Entity` add class file `Actions`

```
namespace App\Entity;

class Actions
{

}
```

you can also use `composer dump-autoload` and check vendor/composer/autoload*  fiels and see if namespaces are registered there.'

Regarding `class_exists()` it does not work with short names or aliases you need to provide the full name of class. I'd suggest using `::class` operator So in your case it would be:

```
<?php
  use App\Entity\Actions;

  class_exists(Actions::class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I changed the auto loader to psr-4, and attached it to this:

```
  "psr-4": {
       "App\\": "src/"
  }
```

**dump-autoload** is exactly what I was looking for, but I don't see any included files or classes listed:

```
    PS C:\wamp64\www\spider\chebi2> composer dump-autoload -vvv
    Reading ./composer.json
    Loading config file ./composer.json
    Checked CA file C:\Users\horse\AppData\Local\Temp\composer-cacert-12fdaece071ee9515fa28aabed5ab089876ae257833106e15a583e060eaff6b5.pem: valid
    Executing command (C:\wamp64\www\spider\chebi2): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
    Executing command (C:\wamp64\www\spider\chebi2): git describe --exact-match --tags
    Executing command (C:\wamp64\www\spider\chebi2): git log --pretty="%H" -n1 HEAD
    Reading C:/Users/horse/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json
    Loading config file C:/Users/horse/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json
    Reading C:\wamp64\www\spider\chebi2/vendor/composer/installed.json
    Reading C:/Users/horse/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/composer/installed.json
    Running 1.2.2 (2016-11-03 17:43:15) with PHP 5.6.25 on Windows NT / 10.0
    Generating autoload file
```

I still can't find the entity classes.

To clarify, I should have the folder structure like this:

```
 - src (contains only subdirectories)
     - Entity (contains the entity files)
     - Repositories
     - App (empty)
```

Comment: look at `'/vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: The autoload.php file itself has only two lines in it, but I checked the vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php file, and it lists all of the packages in the **composer.json** file but doesn't list any of the files that should be autoloaded with the psr4 autoloader. In **autoload_namespaces.php**, it doesn't list any of the namespaces I added. When I ran **composer diagnose**, one of the lines in there is this: `The property psr-4 is not defined and the definition does not allow additional properties`

Comment: So after some reading, it seems I had a misunderstanding is what the `use some\namespace;` command does. I thought that `use App\Entity;` will load the name of every class in that namespace into the globals, but what actually does is create as alias called Entity. So instead I'd need to call the class like this \Entity\Actions. I don't understand it though, because I'm seen with so many different components I've installed through composer, I add `use path\to\namespace;` and then I can just call the classes directly.

Comment: read http://php.net/manual/pl/language.namespaces.basics.php

if you have class A in App\Entity and you declare `use App\Entity` it means you can use name `Entity\A` of class without full namespace. If you want to use single class then you need to write `use App\Entity\A` then you can use `A` class without need to declare full or relative path